# PHP -- int typecast of numeric string value giving 0

Tags: php, int, casting

OK, so there is a page I'm querying on another server that returns a comma separated list of two values. Something it would return would be:

```
850,640
```

I have some PHP code that calls file_get_contents on that page and needs to do some numeric calculations based on the two values.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get an `int` value out of this.

```
$res = trim(file_get_contents('http://thatURL/'));
echo "X" . $res . "X<br/>";
list($x,$y) = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return (int)$a;'), explode(',', $res));

echo "X:$x";
```

results in the output:

```
X 850,640 X
X:0
```

Note the spaces before and after the comma separated values(how the hell? I `trim`'d them!) and that `$x` is assigned the value `0`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried trimming within the custom callback?

Comment: I tried your code with `$res = trim("   850,640   ");` and it works correctly. Are you sure your URL _really_ contains those numbers? Also note that instead of using your own function, you can use intval()

Comment: View Source or printing in plaintext will be immensely useful here. As Hamish points out you may be printing HTML surrounding the whitespace, and as far as I can see you're definitely copying and pasting from the browser's viewport and not the HTML source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using `file_get_contents()` on a URL, there was some HTML being put in as well that I didn't notice in my `echo` because it parsed out... just empty body and html tags. Oops!

Comment: You un-accepted my answer, even thought that's what help you find the cause? :(

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Nothing, as far as I can see, which indicates that the content of $res is not quite what you expect. Could you change the first echo to:

```
echo htmlentities($res);
```

My guess is $res contains some un-printed characters, for example, it is actually:

```
<span> </span>850,640<span> </span>
```

or

```
&nbsp;850,640&nbsp;
```

Comment: You are correct! It had html and body tags in it. Oops. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. The `array_map` and llamda function are arguably overkill for your usage.

```
$res = " 850,640 ";
echo "X" . $res . "X<br/>";
list($x,$y) = explode(',', trim($res));

echo "X:" . (int)$x;
echo "Y:" . (int)$y;
```

Worked for me, but I'm not using `file_get_contents()`. If that doesn't work, something else is being output by the page.

Comment: But when I manually set `$res` to " 850,640 " like you did, it works... it's making me think there's some other non-whitespace character preceding the 850? Is there any way to see?

Comment: There is something else returning from that page. Run it thru `htmlspecialchars()` and see what it spits out.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not a typed language. Use [intval](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert a string to integer.

Correction: it is a loosely typed language! That's what I meant!

Comment: -1 No idea where you heard that PHP is not a typed language. It's not *strictly* typed, but [that doesn't mean it completely lacks distinct data types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php).